# Add a Second Y Axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there a straightforward way to add a second Y-axis to a chart model?  I see that the [linePlusBar](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) chart has this feature (via `y1Axis` `y2Axis` and `forceY`) but is there a simple way to add it to other models? I would like to use it for the lineChart or the scatter models.

Answer (score 0):

Same X axis, different Y value need double Y axis. You could try this:

```
plot(x,y1......,axes=F)
axis(2,....) # build the left Y axis
par(new=T) # means that the next chart will be draw on the picture you draw above
plot(x,y2......,axes=F)
axis(4,....) # build the right Y axis
```